# How to generate series for date range with minutes interval in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

In Postgres below query is working using generate_series function

```
SELECT dates 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2019-03-01' as TIMESTAMP), CAST('2019-04-01' as TIMESTAMP),  interval '30 mins') AS dates
```

Below query is also working in Oracle but only for date interval

```
select to_date('2019-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + rownum -1 as dates 
from all_objects 
where rownum <= to_date('2019-03-06','YYYY-MM-DD')-to_date('2019-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')+1

SELECT dates 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2019-03-01' as TIMESTAMP), CAST('2019-04-01' as TIMESTAMP),  interval '30 mins') AS dates
```

I want same result in Oracle for below query

```
SELECT dates 
FROM generate_series(CAST('2019-03-01' as TIMESTAMP), CAST('2019-04-01' as TIMESTAMP),  interval '30 mins') AS dates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT DATE '2019-03-01' + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE AS dates
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2019-03-01' + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE <= DATE '2019-04-01';
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | DATES               |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 00:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 01:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 01:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 02:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 02:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 03:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 03:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 04:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 04:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 05:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-01 05:30:00 |
> ...
> | 2019-03-31 19:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 20:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 20:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 21:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 21:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 22:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 22:30:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 23:00:00 |
> | 2019-03-31 23:30:00 |
> | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64589aeb33c7281755e86dd7da0c926c)*