# Split datetime over several rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset:

```
|id|       datetimeFrom|        datetimeTo|         Duration|      Duration_Appointment
|193229|  07/09/2021 13:30:00  07/09/2021 17:00:00  210(min)       15(min)
```

What I need to do is to split the count of appointment  (14 appointments) over several records
so the result has to be like this:

```
|id|       datetimeFrom|        datetimeTo|         Duration|      Duration_Appointment
|193229|  07/09/2021 13:30:00  07/09/2021 13:45:00  210(min)       15(min)
|193229|  07/09/2021 13:45:00  07/09/2021 14:00:00  210(min)       15(min)
|193229|  07/09/2021 14:00:00  07/09/2021 14:15:00  210(min)       15(min)  
.....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate series for date range with minutes interval in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690253/how-to-generate-series-for-date-range-with-minutes-interval-in-oracle)

Comment: What do you do if the duration and the appointment duration don't divide evenly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this query should work for you.  The hierarchical one in the linked query may cause you issues when you have multiple records in your source table:

```sql
WITH test_data (ID, datetimefrom, datetimeto, duration, duration_appointment) AS
(
  SELECT 193229, TO_DATE('07/09/2021 13:30:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('07/09/2021 17:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 210, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 122221, TO_DATE('05/06/2021 11:30:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('05/06/2021 14:30:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 180, 20 FROM DUAL
),
appointment_slots (ID, datetimeFrom, datetimeTo, lvl, duration_min) AS
(
  SELECT td.id, td.dateTimeFrom, td.dateTimeFrom+(td.duration_appointment*(1/24/60)), td.duration/td.duration_appointment, td.duration_appointment
  FROM test_data td
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, a.dateTimeTo, a.dateTimeTo+(a.duration_min*(1/24/60)), a.lvl-1, a.duration_min
  FROM appointment_slots a
  WHERE lvl > 1
)
SELECT a.id, a.datetimefrom, a.datetimeto, a.duration_min
FROM appointment_slots a
ORDER BY a.ID, a.datetimefrom;
```